# Particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Suppose we have a non-homogeneous differential equation $Ly=f$ in the ring of exponential sums $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$, then $f=e^{b_i x}$, right?

When $b_i$ is a root of the characteristic equation of the homogeneous equation of multiplicity $M$, then how is the particular solution?

Is it $$y(x)=Cx^Me^{b_i x}$$ or $$y(x)=e^{b_i x} (A_0+A_1x+ \dots +A_{M}x^{M})$$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$ y(x)=e^{b_i x} (A_0+A_1x+ \dots +A_{M-1}x^{M-1})$$
solves the homogeneous equation $Ly = 0$, you can use either.  But using the first form will probably be less work.

Comment: So, in this ring the differential equation has only a solution when $b_i$ is not a root of the characteristic equation of the homogeneous equation, right? Since in this ring the polynomials of $x$ are not defined.

Comment: Yes.  I think that is correct.

Comment: Does the fact that $b_i$ is not a root of the characteristic equation of the homogeneous equation mean that $$Lf \neq 0$$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is definitely correct for constant coefficient ODE.

Comment: A differential equation in this ring is of the form $$Lx=\sum_{i=0}^N \alpha_i e^{b_i x}$$ and applying the superposition principle we get the equations $$Lx=e^{b_i x}, \ i=0, \dots , N$$ Is my previous comment correct also for the initial differential eqiation, i.e., $$L \left (\sum_{i=0}^N \alpha_i e^{b_i x}\right ) =0$$ ? Or isn't it true when we have a sum?

Comment: I meant $$L \left (\sum_{i=0}^N \alpha_i e^{b_i x}\right )  \neq 0$$

Comment: If the $b_i$ are distinct, then yes, because $L\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i e^{b_i x} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^N \gamma_i e^{b_i x}$ where the $\gamma_i$ are non-zero, and $e^{b_i x}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: I see... When we are considering the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$ the differential equation is of the form $$Ly=\sum_{i=0}^N \alpha_i x^i$$ By looking for solutions I found out that the non-homogeneous equation has always at least one solution, and the homogeneous equation has a solution only if at least one root of the characteristic equation is equal to $0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Can we formulate it as follows? $$L(e^0)=0 \Rightarrow L(1)=0$$ ?

Comment: Look, I think you generally understand what is going on.  But I have a lot going on in my life right now, so I cannot keep up this correspondence.  Sorry.